# pass html code to worpdress

Tags: php, theme-development, customization, templates

I'm starting with wordpress and I have some doubts.

I created a proprietary design from requirements that had. This design is made with html and bootstrap. Now I want to start using wordpress step then as the pages that I have the layout I made to wordpress?

When I paste the html code when I create a new page, my code has things like this ...

```
<a href="#"> <img src = "<? php echo get_template_directory_uri ();?> / images/clean/32x32/facebook.png" alt = "Facebook"> </ a>
```

or php code which is not interpreted. How should I? I tried to give the image add text box but would have to upload the images, but if you and I have in the theme!!

Answer (score 1):

Resources in the Theme package don't belong in `post_content`. Images in `post_content` need to be uploaded and attached from within WordPress.

If you want to add images and content to the page template itself, refer to [Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates).